# Developing novel association measure with t-SNE

Tags: python, tsne, neuroimaging

I am an MSc. student in computing and I am currently writing my thesis on radiogenomics (imaging genomics) for brain cancer research. I NEED YOUR HELP.

My supervisor and I are thinking about developing a novel tool to test association between two datasets.

Essentially, in this project, I will have two datasets: i) Gene mutations, and ii) Imaging data.

One way to find associations between the multi-view datasets is to perform Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA). However, this has been done before and often with poor results.

So what we are thinking about is the following algorithmic approach:

1. Reduce dimensions of both datasets using either PCA (reduction) or
   random forest (selection)
2. Visualise both datasets separately with
   t-SNE
3. Compare neighbors: Pick an ID/subject in one visualization and
   find its neighbors. Then pick the same ID in the other visualisation
   and see if neighbors are the same.
4. Do this for all IDs
5. Use some metric to assess performance. If neighbours are similar the
   performance should be high.

How does this sound? More concretely:

1. Does the overall approach make sense?
2. To identify neighbors, I am thinking of using the Perplexity parameter of t-SNE (i.e. if perplexity = 30, pick 30 closest neighbours). Makes sense?
3. What would be a good metric to report aggregate results for this new algorithm?

Thanks a lot!

Best,

Comment: Why can't you just concatenate the two datasets along id's and then use tsne to visualize the result?

Comment: Hi @AlexR. Thanks! But how would that help? I wouldn't be able to use it as an association measure, would I?

Comment: Could you define "performance" here? I mean, what you're saying is that if you cluster both datasets, you kind of expect the same id's around eachother in both datasets. But that doesn't really define performance. If you were to concatenate the datasets, you'd see people who are simultaneously similar in both datasets, which seems to be the goal? So your association measure is nearest neighbors.